# How to color a treeview node in its width in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, colors, treeview

The drawing below illustrates what I want to do. I have a piece of code but this one only allows the selection of the text, not its width. Maybe there are some treeview properties to transform, like FullRowSelect (false or true)? Claude.

```
    Private Sub TreeView1_DrawNode(sender As Object, e As DrawTreeNodeEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.DrawNode
    
Dim r As New Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, treeView1.ClientSize.Width, e.Bounds.Height)

            If (e.State And TreeNodeStates.Selected) <> 0 Then
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, e.Bounds)
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, e.Node.NodeFont, e.Bounds,
            System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.Empty,
            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
            Else
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds)
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, e.Node.NodeFont, e.Bounds,
            SystemColors.WindowText, System.Drawing.Color.Empty,
            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
            End If
    
        End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `e.Bounds` is the node dimensions.  You don't *have* to restrict it to that.

Comment: How can I change the dimensions of the rectangle (e.Bounds)?

Comment: Make your own.  `Dim r As New Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, treeView1.ClientSize.Width, e.Bounds.Height)`

Comment: vb.Net gives me an error: Too many arguments for 'Public Overloads Sub New ()'?

Comment: `Public Overloads Sub New ()` has nothing to do with my code.  Or did you create your own Rectangle class or something?

Comment: in the Private Sub TreeView1_DrawNode...

Comment: Update your post with the new code.  I can't see your code from here.

Comment: Your posted code doesn't produce that error.  You have something else going on.  Replace the `e.Bounds` with `r` in the `e.Graphics,FillRectangle` method calls.

Comment: Done, but it's the same! Same error BC30057. No information otherwise! I tested in another project and it works! :) I don't know why in my project, it is wrong!

Comment: Did you create your own Rectangle class by any chance?  Try `Dimr r As New System.Drawing.Rectangle(...` and see if that works.

Comment: Great, it works now! :) Thanks LarsTech. I will try to make the height of the rectangle a little bigger. Thanks again for helping out.